# Simple Java 2D Game : Player Doesn't Move

Tags: java, 2d, debugging

I'm a beginner at java and I'm trying to make a simple 2D game as a practice, and i have a problem here with the player, I've tried a lot to make it move but it didn't work. These are the classes that contain the player.

Game Class :

```
package game;

import game.input.Controller;
import game.input.KeyInput;
import game.objects.Player;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class Game extends JPanel implements ActionListener{

  Timer loopTimer;
  //Objects
  Player p;
  Controller c;

  public Game(){
    addKeyListener(new KeyInput(p));
    setFocusable(true);

    loopTimer = new Timer(10, this);
    loopTimer.start();

    p = new Player(300,200);
    c = new Controller();
  }

  public void paint(Graphics g){
    super.paint(g);
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
    g2d.setColor(Color.white);
    g2d.fillRect(0, 0, 640, 480);
    p.draw(g2d);
    c.draw(g2d);
  }

  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ee){
    p.update();
    c.update();
    repaint();
  }    
}
```

Player Class :

```
package game.objects;

import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;

public class Player extends GlobalPosition {

  private String playerimage = "/images/marioR.png";

  int velX = 0;
  int velY = 0;

  public Player(int x, int y) {
    super(x, y);
  }

  public void draw(Graphics2D g2d){
    g2d.drawImage(getPlayerImage(), x, y, null);
  }

  public Image getPlayerImage(){
    ImageIcon i = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource(playerimage));
    return i.getImage();
  }

  public void update(){
    x += velX;
    y += velY;

    // Collision with outside
    if(x < 0){ 
      x = 0;
    }
    if(y < 0){
      y = 0;
    }
    if(x > 640){
      x = 640;
    }
    if(y > 480){
      y = 480;
    }
  }

  public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e){
    int c = e.getKeyCode();
    if(c == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT){
      velX = -10;
    }
    if(c == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT){
      velX = 10;
    }
    if(c == KeyEvent.VK_UP){
      velY = -10;
    }
    if(c == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN){
      velY = 10;
    }
  }

  public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e){
    int c = e.getKeyCode();
    if(c == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT){
      velX = 0;
    }
    if(c == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT){
      velX = 0;
    }
    if(c == KeyEvent.VK_UP){
      velY = 0;
    }
    if(c == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN){
      velY = 0;
    }
  }

  public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e){
  }
}
```

KeyInput Class :

```
package game.input;

import game.objects.Player;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

public class KeyInput extends KeyAdapter{

  private final Player p;

  public KeyInput(Player p){
    this.p = p;
  }

  public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e){
    p.keyPressed(e);
  }

  public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e){
    p.keyReleased(e);
  }
}
```

.

Comment: Please fix the formatting of this question, it's incredibly difficult to discern anything valuable from this code.

Comment: _"it didn't work"_ is a very non descriptive way to describe your issue. What behaviour do you expect (make character move, yeah, how??), and what did you get instead?

Answer (score 2):

`actionPerformed()` is never called, so nothing is updated or repainted. You need to register it. To check that it's registered, simple add `System.out.println("I Work!!!!")` to the body of the method.

Also, a tip for a new Java programmer: place the `@override` annotation before methods you override. In your case, add it on the lines before `keyPressed()` and `keyReleased` in the `KeyInput` class.

Please take this the right way. Don't just jump into creating a game until you fully understand the language you're working with. There are tons of resources online (articles, texts, videos, etc...) that will teach you Java quickly. It's not a hard language to learn. Master it first, then developing a game will be no problem!

Comment: Did this fix your issue? Please give me a check if so, thank you. This forum is built on reputation.